# CakePHP 3.5 how to validate an empty or not empty field based on the value of another field?

Tags: validation, cakephp, rule, cakephp-3.5

I am using CakePHP 3.5.5.

I am struck with a custom validation rule. I have country and state fields in my view. In case if the value of country field is US then we make state field required otherwise we don't. I have put a custom validation rule in my UsersTable.php like this:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
  $validator
    ->add('state', 'custom', [
    'rule' => [$this,'validate_state'],
    'provider' => 'custom',
    'message' => 'Please enter state'
  ]);
}
```

and have created validate_state function like this:

```
public function validate_state($value, $context) {
    //debug($value, $context);die;
//if state is us)
  //if state is not empty return true;
  //if state is empty return false;
//else return true;
}
```

But it not working at all. The only thing it is doing is showing the "This field cannot be left empty" message if I use this rule. I understand that CakePHP assumes to run *notEmpty* on its own if you have created a validator rule for a field. But my problem is I cannot rule field value true or false before checking the value of another field for which I need to use custom function before checking the notEmpty method. But in my case here if I dont use notEmpty method it neither is entering the custom function validate_state nor it is showing the custom message i use in this rule.

Do you know a better way to do it without hacking the form request data before sending it to validator?

Answer (score 1):

Use a callable for the `notEmpty` (or `allowEmpty`) rule, and just like you'd do it in your `custom` rule, evaluate the context to determine whether the rules applies (ie whether the field must not be empty), something along the lines of:

```
$validator
    ->notEmpty('state', null, function ($context) {
        // field must not be empty when the conditions evaluate to true
        return
            isset($context['data']['country']) &&
            $context['data']['country'] === 'US';
    })
    // ...
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Validation > Conditional Validation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#conditional-validation)**